# Where to Store Metadata

Tags: database

We've built an algorithm that helps us deliver relevant articles to our users.  In the background during certain intervals, the algorithm will calculate metadata, such as average age, age spread, and gender coefficient from a slew of data related to views, comments, and votes.

With that said, are there any downsides to storing this metadata as fields on the Articles table?  Or, should I create a separate table, such as Article_Data, to store the information?  I am just not sure how much the updating of this metadata will interfere with selecting the articles.

For the most part, we will be SELECTing articles and its metadata and JOINing it on user data (age, gender, etc) to show users relevant content.  The only time we don't need the metadata is when we show a particular article to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are clearly defined, and there are a limited number of them, put them in the Articles table.

If you are going to store more than one record of metadata fields per article, you need another table, in a one-to-many relationship with the Articles table.

If the fields are not clearly defined, user-defined, or there are many of them, you probably need a new table with one row per metadata item.  But this is more difficult to work with in the long run.

**See Also**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model